# foreach loop error in rss fetch

Tags: php, rss

I am trying to get the links from the rss feed but I am getting the below error while doing so

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/sss/public_html/radiorss/feedcrawler.php on line 1`1

Below is the code I am running to get the values.

```
    <?php
    include 'xml_regex.php';
    include 'simple_html_dom.php';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'www.newsonair.nic.in/NSD.asp');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $xml = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    foreach($item as $item) {
      echo $item->title.'<br />';
      echo $item->pubDate.'<br />';
      echo $item->link.'<br />';
      echo $item->description.'<br />';
      echo $item->enclosure.'<br />';
    }

?>
```

Please help me to know where I am wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, you don't parse your xml in to [`SimpleXML`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or a [`DOMDocument`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: where is $item defined?

Comment: @Raidenace $item is in that rss feed :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/sss/public_html/radiorss/feedcrawler.php on line 11

This type of error indicates that you didn't pass an array to the foreach construct.

Your first issue is you need to make sure $item is an initialized array. Your code example doesn't show where it's being defined. You will have to track it back to it's origin and make sure it's value is an array of w/e objects. The var_dump() function is useful for this purpose.

Your next issue is your're overwriting the value of the array in the foreach.

```
foreach($item as $item) {
...
}
```

Needs to be something like...

```
foreach($items as $item) or foreach($item as $aItem)
```